# Google Play upgrading from Alpha testing

Tags: android, google-play

I put a version of my app into Alpha testing. I've assigned 2 of the office phones to be Alpha testers. I sent the invite to be testers to the test phones, they accepted and downloaded the app.

So far so good. On the tester's phones, i've checked the show notifications' check box in settings->apps->myApp->show notifications. I have then uploaded a new version of the app to Alpha testing as well incrementing the version number.

When will the Alpha test phones receive the upgrade? Do i have to invite them again to download the update?

I was under the impression that the app would seamlessly upgrade if the above checkbox was  checked.

thanks in advance

Matt

Comment: `settings->apps->myApp->show notifications` has nothing to do with the update system. This setting is a general setting which allows/denies the app to create/show notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When will the Alpha test phones receive the upgrade? Do i have to
>   invite them again to download the update?

You don't have to invite if you've already invited your testers, they are going to see all alpha updates. In my experiences it nearly takes 2 hours.

> On the tester's phones, i've checked the show notifications' check box
>   in settings->apps->myApp->show notifications.

Thus your tester is going to see update as a notification if automatic updates are allowed. Or they can browse google play store with their google account which is invited as a tester.

Flow is just like google play production versions. Only difference is that your app in alpha state is only visible to your testers.

Comment: Do you have any more info on when the automatic update happens for people on the alpha list? For me it seems to not happen at all, or maybe with a very long delay.

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere it has same exprience to release publishing. But only users at alpha or beta testers are having update notification.

Comment: So you're saying eventually people will get automatic updates?

Comment: Yes, the people in the alpha testers for alpha stage and the beta testers for beta stage are getting automatic updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot - will be helpful for others here to have this this explicit :)

Answer (score 0):

All the devices that have installed the Alpha version from the Play Store will automatically receive the updated version after you publish it.

Of course, just as with "regular" (release) versions, there is a verification & distribution process (within Play Store) that takes place between you publishing the new version and devices being notified that there is a new version available. It usually takes less than 1 (calendar) day.

FYI the link that should be passed to your alpha testers is: https://play.google.com/apps/testing/your_app_package

Comment: ok thanks. Can i run Alpha testing alongside Beta testing(at the same time)? Or do i have to move testing from Alpha to Beta. We have 20 customers. I want to assign one company to Alpha, the other to Beta. If they are both happy, then the app will be moved to production where the other 18 companies get the app.

Comment: @turtleboy yes you can run alpha and beta testing at the same time. You can directly publish an app to beta testing or move from alpha to beta. And define different testers for alpha and beta testing.

Comment: @aegean so i can assign company 1 as alpha, let them install it. Then move it to beta, where company 2 installs it? Once moved to beta, is it removed from Alpha? thanks

Comment: yes, if you move your apk from alpha to beta, it will be no longer visible to alpha testers.